# Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module in magento 2 .?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have use `mCustomScrollbar` jquery plugin but there some error have come & error like:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module..

Help appreciated.

Thanks.

My mCustomScrollbar jquery plugin code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mCustomScrollbar',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($, mCustomScrollbar) {
    'use strict';

    /*mcustomScrollbar plugin code here...*/

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call js file  in `default_head_blocks.xml`

> `#app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`
>
> `<script src="js/mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>`

Place  file under `/app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/web/js`

Comment: not working..!!!

Comment: yes js file is calling but i have face some module related error..like
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module....

Comment: Please update your question with  actual errors, because you have asked for adding of JS library . Right question will grab right person to help you

Comment: have you got solution of it?